# Probability problem; adding elements to a list then picking from that list

Tags: probability, random

It seems like a very simple problem but I couldn't figure out the solution myself (not homework)

Simplified it's the following:

`10% chance to add 1 to a list
20% chance to add 2 to a list
30% chance to add 3 to a list
40% chance to add 4 to a list`

and from that list I pick 1 number.

How much chance is there to get a specific number?
Running a simulation in matlab gave me:
`29.3%   to get 4;
20.9%   to get 3;
13.5%   to get 2;
6.2%    to get 1;`
30.1%   to get 0 numbers in a list so no number could be picked.

Comment: The % to get 0 numbers is (1-0.1) * (1-0.2) * (1-0.3) * (1-0.4) = 30.24%

Answer (score 1):

Let $p(n)\ (n\in\{1,2,3,4\})$ be the probability that number $n$ is added to the list (e.g., your $0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4$). Then a formula for the probability that the outcome is the specific number $x$ is 
$$1(Abcd)+{1\over 2}(ABcd+AbCd+AbcD)+{1\over 3}(ABCd+ABcD+AbCD)+{1\over 4}(ABCD)
$$
where
$$\begin{align}A&=p(x)\\
B&=p(1+(x\bmod 4))\\
C&=p(1+((x+1)\bmod 4))\\
D&=p(1+((x+2)\bmod 4))\\
\end{align}$$ 
and $a=1-A,\ b=1-B,\ c=1-C,\ d=1-D.$

Note that $B,C,D$ are simply the add-to-the-list probabilities for the three *other* numbers besides $x$, and *they may be taken in any order*. (The above formula just uses $\bmod 4$ to express the choice of taking them in cyclic order.)

In Sage:

```
def p(x): return [1/10, 2/10, 3/10, 4/10][x-1]
def Pout(x):
    A = p(x)
    B = p(1 + (x%4))
    C = p(1 + ((x+1)%4))
    D = p(1 + ((x+2)%4))
    a = 1 - A
    b = 1 - B
    c = 1 - C
    d = 1 - D
    return (A*b*c*d)+(A*B*c*d+A*b*C*d+A*b*c*D)/2+(A*B*C*d+A*B*c*D+A*b*C*D)/3+(A*B*C*D)/4

print [Pout(x) for x in [1..4]], 1-sum([Pout(x) for x in [1..4]])
print [Pout(x).n() for x in [1..4]], 1-sum([Pout(x).n() for x in [1..4]])

[473/7500, 1981/15000, 521/2500, 4411/15000] 189/625
[0.0630666666666667, 0.132066666666667, 0.208400000000000, 0.294066666666667] 0.302400000000000
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is an easy way.  The chance you get $4$ is 
$0.4$ (that you added $4$ at all) times $\Big[(1-0.1)(1-0.2)(1-0.3)$ (that it is the only number on the list) plus $\frac 12\big(0.1(1-0.2)(1-0.3)+(1-0.1)0.2(1-0.3)+(1-0.1)(1-0.2)0.3\big)$ (because one other number was added) plus $\ldots\Big]$ and the dots have the cases where two or three other numbers were added.

Comment: Yeah I got as far but that is not an efficient solution; especially not when working with 20 cases; 

0.4*0.7*0.8*0.9 + 
0.5*0.4*0.3*0.8*0.9 + 0.5*0.4*0.7*0.2*0.9 + 0.5*0.4*0.7*0.8*0.1 + 
0.3333*0.4*0.3*0.2*0.9 + 0.3333 * 0.4* 0.7  * 0.2 * 0.1 + 0.3333 * 0.4 * 0.3 * 0.8 * 0.1 + 
0.25 * 0.4 * 0.3 * 0.2 * 0.1

(Case where you only can pick 4) +
(Cases where you can pick 4 + 1 other number)
(Cases where you can pick 4 + 2 other numbers)
(Cases where you can pick 4 + 3 other numbers)

I was thinking that I must be missing something

Comment: I don’t think you were missing anything. Solving problems like this with a neat formula depends on the problem having symmetry. If the chance of adding each number were the same you could just find the chance you don’t get any number, subtract from $1$, and divide by $4$ because of the symmetry. Here you don’t have that, so you have to go through the cases.